# JQUERY not calling ready - JavascriptResources in eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse

I have added jQuery Library 2.1 as javascriptResource in the project. As shown in the picture.

[image]

In the index.html, the autocomplete for ready works but, ready function is not called.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Hello");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: your tags are mismatched, move your closing `</script>` tag before`</head><body>`

Comment: your jquery reference is not showing in your html page

Comment: Jquery2.1 is included in JavascriptResource. How should I include the reference in javascriptResource?

Comment: try to see javascript console and check if any errors there. Probably you move the <script> block to under <body> as what bruchowski said. I think maybe you jquery resource is automatically inserted(if it does) after this script block and cause the "$" symbol to be undefined when this block of script is been executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having it available under `JavaScript Resources` makes it known to the tools, and available for Content Assist at edit-time. It doesn't change the behavior at *runtime* in the browser--something still has to reference the jQuery file from your web page, like a `script` tag.

Comment: Later on I added jQuery all files in the WebContent folder and then use the source path(in the script tag) to reference the files and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the jquery script. Example:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Hope it helps.

Comment: Jquery2.1 is already included. But, how should I include a jquery2.1 in JavaScriptReesource.

Comment: You need to include the path of the javascript file with jquery: 

<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery/jquery-xxxxx.js"></script>

Navigate the project under the file explorer and try to find it. Sorry for bad english.